# how to write the script to know each sample's cluster number?

Tags: single-cell

I have followed the Seurat T[utorial:Integrating stimulated vs. control PBMC datasets](https://satijalab.org/seurat/immune_alignment.html) to learn cell-type specific responses by using my data. And I am confused about how to write the script to calculate the cell number of each sample on each cluster.

I have run TSENPlot to know the samples and I'm using another TSENPlot to get the clusters. If I want to know find the cluster1 of each sample's number how can I write the script?

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give us some more details. What exactly do you need? Can you show us the code you have run?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are following the basic seurat guide:

```
pbmc@ident
```

You can access the `'ident'` slot of your Seurat object and you will get a vector of the cluster IDs and the names will be the respective cells.

```
head(seuratobj@ident)
Cell1A7 Cell1C4 Cell1D1 Cell1D2 Cell1D3 Cell1D5
0 3 3 1 3 1 
Levels: 0 1 2 3 4
```

Comment: In my example, the printing wasn't great but essentially Cell1A7 is in cluster 0, Cell 1C4 is in cluster 3, etc...